# jQuery Versions on Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I got an problem on an Wordpress Theme

I include the Nivo Slider (jQuery) and a jquery flexylisder.

now I´ve problems with my Plugin -> "Ether Content Builder"

The Nivo Slider is out of function...

The Header

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>   
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="wp-content/themes/psr_v1/js/jquery.flexislider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and thats bevore the body tag

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/psr_v1/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slidder').nivoSlider();
});
</script>
```

how can I make that everything works ? 
I test the jquery.noConflict() but it doesn´t works..

Answer (score 2):

Is the div id you are attaching NivoSlider to actually called 'slidder' or is that a typo?

If that isn't it then try using the following (cheers Jezen)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $('#slidder').nivoSlider();
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

- EDIT

Right first of all that is a really old version of jQuery you are loading for some reason, that will cause all sorts of issues even if you do get it going.

Altogether.  Wordpress ships with jQuery, you just have to enqueue it.  In your functions.php enqueue both it and then then scripts that depend on it;

```
if ( !is_admin() ) {
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.nivoslider', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js', array('jquery'));
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.flexislider', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.flexislider.js', array('jquery'));       
}
```

- EDIT again.

Right I've got into work and had a look at your source.  You've done as I've said and enqueued your scripts in functions.php - they are now getting loaded into the head proplery.  However, you need to remove the stuff you've got in your footer.  At the moment it looks like;

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/psr_v1/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>  


 <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slidder').nivoSlider();
});
</script>

<script src="wp-content/themes/psr_v1/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="wp-content/themes/psr_v1/js/jquery.flexislider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It needs to look like this (courtesy of Jezen);

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $('#slidder').nivoSlider();
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: Yes the div called slidder because the Flesyslider on the page called slider.

I try the <?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?> bevore the head
and your code but it doesnt work

Comment: No don't copy into the head - as my edit says, you add that code block into your functions.php file and that will load in the scripts properly, in the correct order. Yes, you delete the manual insertion of the scripts in the header and footer.

Comment: Hmm i copy your code in the function.php and include this in my index.php 
but it doesn´t work - now all plugins doesn´t works

Comment: if it helps the domain is [link](http://psr.mediameans.de)
on the "Startseite" it doesn´t works and on the other pages it works

Comment: Are you using a child theme? That would stop get_bloginfo from getting the right directory.

Comment: Right let's have another go - I have edited the answer again.

Comment: You don't need to enqueue scripts with a `functions.php` file, and you don't need to prefix jQuery methods with `jQuery` when you're already passing in `$` as the function argument.

Comment: +1 for editing that in, but don't forget that you need to load the plugins *before* initialising them, *i.e.*, `$('#slidder').nivoSlider();` needs to be the *last* thing you do.

Comment: i do... the last thing i load is the slider.nivoslider but it doesn´t works

Comment: You have a JS error - it's in Flexislider.js and it's the $(window).load(function(){ . This has gotten into a bit of a mess, sorry @user1535752 . Remove the include to the flexislider, get the Nivoslider working first and then change Line 16 of Flexislider to correspond to the comments by Jezen.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Remove this line:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2 - Your scripts should go before your closing body tag, so put them in your `footer.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/psr_v1/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $('#slidder').nivoSlider();
    }(jQuery));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good of you to join us. He wasn't passing in $ as a function in the argument and his scripts weren't loading in at all at the beginning - I only got a link to the site this morning so I was trying to help blind. As you can see from the comments a lot of effort went into getting to the stage where you could come in and contribute.

Comment: That's right, he wasn't, but *you* are. Your line here: `jQuery(window).load(function($)`. You see the dollar sign in between those brackets? You're passing in `$` as an argument to the function. That gives the `$` local scope inside that code block.

Comment: OK - I understand.  Thanks for the explanation, I didn't realise that was unnecessary as it has always worked fine for me. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: hmm I changed your edits but it doesn´t works oyu can look at my link